# Page numbers appear with hyphens in the Table of Contents in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Here is a [downloadable sample of my Word](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjkHDd287OtVZ01J_PUv3hmnves?e=YDGYii) document.

I have created a custom table of contents in my word document. However, the pages numbers in my "Table of Contents" appear with the **hyphens** like this:

[image: Table of Contents screenshot]

The page numbers in the table of contents appear same as the page numbers format in the page footer.
I am not able to prevent the hyphens from appearing in the "Table of Contents". How can I remove/prevent the hyphens from appearing in the "Table of Contents"?

Here is a screenshot from the TOC dialog.

[[image: The relevant format in the ToC WIndow:][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8VVv.png)

Comment: Can you show us the relevant format in the ToC WIndow?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad.... I have added the relevant format in the ToC WIndow.

Comment: I suspect that you have formatted your page numbers in the Format Page Numbers dialog to include the hyphens.

Comment: @   
Charles Kenyon, I have added a link to my word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem.

[image: screenshot]

#### You need to change the formatting of your page numbers in the Format Page Numbers Dialog.

[image: screenshot]

If you need the hyphens in your footer (or header) insert them there, not in the page number format.

Comment: Yes, I need the hyphens in the footer. I followed your instructions and the issue has been resolved. Perfect, thank you very much.